Updated from 22.04 to 24.04 and now I can't access the GUI
I updated my system by clicking on one of those update windows that usually indicate availability of new software. I didn't think top much about it and let the system do its thing. However, now whenever I turn the computer on I only get a blank screen. By holding on left shift or pressing esc I managed to get to the command line, but the GUI is nowhere to be found.
How can I fix this? If I need to reinstall Ubuntu, I will also need to perform a full backup from the command line, as I didn't think of this before doing the actual update.

See the question and its answer: Failed update to 24.04 as well as the answers to the linked duplicate.
